# Netbeans platform disable an action

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

On my application, I need to display a "Create project" button if I have the role "admin", otherwise if just a simple user, the action should be disabled and the button should not be displayed at all.

Here is my code:

```
@ActionID(id = "com.demos.core.action.project.ProjectCreateAction", category = "Actions")
@ActionRegistration(displayName = "com.demos.core.Bundle#action.project.projectcreate", iconBase = "com/demos/core/action/create_project.png")
@ActionReference(path = "Actions/Ribbon/TaskPanes/group-project/set-project",position = 10)
public final class ProjectCreateAction implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the actionPerformed() method, I'm able to get the user role, but it is too late, I don't want to display the action button at all.

How can I hide this action button if my user is not allowed to use it?

Answer (score 0):

One of possible ways is to implement **Presenter.Toolbar** from package org.openide.util.actions like this:

```
// Some Annotations here
public final class SomeAction extends AbstractAction implements Presenter.Toolbar {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Some action
    }

    @Override
    public Component getToolbarPresenter() {
        ImageIcon icon = ImageUtilities.loadImageIcon("path/to/image.png", true);
        JButton button = new JButton(icon);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setToolTipText(NbBundle.getMessage(SomeAction.class, "TextID"));
        button.setVisible(SomeUtilityClass.isAdmin());
        return button;
    }
}
```